# What is the radius of torsion, geometrically?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

In studying calculus of space curves, we calculate the quantities "curvature" ($\kappa$) and "torsion"($\tau$). Both have inverse-length as units, so their reciprocals $\frac{1}{\kappa}$ and $\frac{1}{\tau}$ have units of length, and are called "radius of curvature" and "radius of torsion".

I understand that radius of curvature is the radius of a curve's osculating circle at a point. That's is a pretty clear notion geometrically, but I struggle to obtain a corresponding notion for radius of torsion.

Can anyone share a geometric intuition behind this length, and what it tells us about a non-planar curve? According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OsculatingSphere.html, the osculating sphere does not have radius $\frac{1}{\tau}$, so it's not that. Calling it a "radius" seems to imply that it's a radius *of* something.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

---

Edit: If a helix is given by $\left<a\cos t,a\sin t,bt\right>$, ($a$ and $b$ positive), then the curvature is $\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$ and the torsion is $\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$. There's a lovely duality there, and if you define a dual helix by swapping $a$ and $b$, then the curvature of one is the torsion of the other, and vice versa. Thus, we could say that the radius of torsion is the radius of curvature for a "dual" helix, but I hesitate to define a whole new kind of duality just to awkwardly impart meaning to a phrase I saw in a book. I don't know whether people who know a lot about helices think this way.

I'm still hoping there's a more natural answer out there.

Comment: Where did you see the term "radius of torsion" used?  This is the first I'm hearing about it.

Comment: If you look up "torsion of a curve" on Wikipedia or Mathworld, it's defined in both articles.

Comment: There is an animation on Wikipedia which might help understanding the meaning of torsion, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve

Comment: That animation is great for understanding torsion as a measurement of how fast the binormal vector rotates about the tangent vector, but it doesn't really illuminate what "radius of torsion" represents, as a length.

Comment: There's [**osculating sphere**](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=FWbCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=osculating+sphere&source=bl&ots=gb5LAhXL5c&sig=ld9JXfVxTIIlSq5XPEmVyxxCYeA&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPndS3hKXPAhXFtpQKHefNC6QQ6AEIajAN#v=onepage&q=osculating%20sphere&f=false) which has third order of contact with the curve.

Comment: Yeah, it's radius isn't $1/\tau$, though. I mentioned that in my question.

Comment: I've worked in differential geometry my whole life and have never before come across this term. I do not see an interpretation other than by analogy with the definition of radius of curvature. Here's something a bit better: The mapping to the unit sphere given by $T(s)$ is called the tangent indicatrix; that given by $B(s)$ is called the binormal indicatrix. The speed of the tangent indicatrix is $\kappa$ and the speed of the binormal indicatrix is $\tau$. Perhaps someone sees something to get out of this ...

Answer (score 3):

I had also came across the notion of "radius of torsion" in the context of a lecture on Frenet-Serret system of equations, and had great difficulties in trying to conceptualize it. The notion of "radius of torsion" is a little more abstract then the "radius of curvature", and cannot be given a direct geometric interpretation as in the case of the letter. One reason for this difference is that torsion cannot exist without curvature; if one tries to define a space curve with non-zero torsion but zero curvature, then the torsion degenerates into curvature.

However, great background and guidance is given to this subject simply by reading a little about the history of differential geometry of space curves. Much earlier than the publication of Frenet-Serret formulas, Alexis Clariault reffered to general space curves as "**curves of double curvature**". This simple renaming gives some clue about conceptualization of torsion and curvature of general space curves.

**Interpretation**:

Assume $\gamma$ is a space curve traced by a point particle. Let $TN$ be it's local osculating plane at some point $X$ (the plane spanned by the tangent vector $T$ and the normal vector $N$), and $BT$ also be a local plane perpendicular to it (it's the plane spanned by the tangent vector $T$ and the binormal vector $B$. Now, let us project the curve $\gamma$ into each of the planes $TN$ and $BT$. One can do this simply by illuminating on the particle from the (local) $B$ and $N$ directions, and then looking at the curves which the particle's shadow traces in each plane.

Obviously, the local curvature of the curve traced by the shadow in the $TN$ plane is $\kappa$. In the same way, the local curvature of of the curve traced in the $TB$ plane is the torsion $\tau$; this gives a straightforward interpretation of the "radius of torsion" - this is radius of the circle which has second order contact with the projection of $\gamma$ into the local $TB$ plane.

A partial illustation of this interpretation can be seen in this picture; it shows the osculating ($TN$) plane and the $BT$ plane.

[image]

**Caution**:

I have not proved yet this claim with full rigourosity; but but nevertheless i wrote it down to make some contribution to the resolution of this question. I think that proving this claim will be my final attempt before i give up the attempts to gain intuition about the "radius of torsion" (and i hope my claim is correct!).

Comment: This is amazing, especially after waiting almost three-and-a-half years! Thank you so much. I'll probably accept this answer later today, but I want to read it more carefully first. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! but first you should really read my answer carefully, since i really didn't intend this answer to be the concluding remark on the notion of "radius of torsion". This is not a ripe conception, and i myself need to proccess it a bit more in my mind.

Comment: I think it will be better to attempt to conceptualize the notion of radius of torsion of space curve using the "osculating sphere" instead of a Gauss's mapping (and then project it into the tangent plane), but i'm still exploring this concept. I'll update my answer if there will be any advances.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not correct. From the Frenet equations you can derive the local canonical form (assuming the curve is $C^3$ or better). The projection in the $TB$-plane (rectifying plane) looks like $$(u+o(u^2), (\kappa_0\tau_0/6)u^3 + o(u^3)).$$ Indeed, it's called the rectifying plane because this projection flattens the curve to have zero curvature at the point. P.S. Both $1/\kappa$ and $1/\tau$ show up in the radius of the osculating *sphere*, but sadly the $1/\tau$ is multiplied by $(1/\kappa)'$.

Comment: After reading your comment i went to wikipedia and saw that the projection into the **TB** plane really traces a cubic polynomial. So i'm sorry i was eventually unable to help... it's really an interesting question how to give a meaningful interpretation to the "radius of torsion".